# Register in Django with email as unique

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and I am trying to make my first registration app. I used the `UserCreationForm`. When I run the code and try to register, if I put the same email form many user it doesn't give me any error.

My forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib import messages

# Create your views here.
from .forms import RegisterForm

def registerUser(request):
     form = RegisterForm()
     if request.method == 'POST':
         form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             form.save()
             return redirect('login')

     else:
         form = RegisterForm()
     return render(request, 'register.html', {'form':form})

def loginUser(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
         username = request.POST.get('username')
         password = request.POST.get('password')

         if username and password:

              user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

              if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')
              else:
                   messages.error(request, 'Username or Password is Incorrect')
        else:
              messages.error(request, 'Fill out all the fields') 

       return render(request, 'login.html', {})

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html', {})


def logoutUser(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('home')

def Profile(request):
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {})
```

Comment: django auth_user model don't take email as unique. so many users can use single email for registration. if you want to use email as unique, use models.BaseUser model to create new user model. upvote if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by Harshil Suthar in the comments, overriding the default user model is the best practise (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example), but it may be a lot of effort in your case if you just want to check unique email when using your form.

You can solve this problem using the clean_< attribute > method of your form. Note that it will just be effective when using this form. So, for example a superuser will still be able to have the same email as another user...

```py
# Other imports...
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise ValidationError("An user with this email already exists!")
        return email
```